# Altering lightbox gallery from vertical to horizontal

Tags: jquery, html

As my title state lightbox has an open gallery example like [this](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/). Can someone give me a tip or an idea on how to change it from horizontal to vertical.

Since I was about to ask this question and I figured out the answer before I post I would like to share the solution.

Prerequisite:

Latest JQuery.js

```
1.<script src="light-box/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
2.<link href="light-box/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

3.<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#gallery a').lightBox();
            });
    </script>`
4.      <style type="text/css">
/* jQuery lightBox plugin - Gallery style */
#gallery {
    background-color: #444;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 135px;
}
#gallery ul { list-style: none; }
#gallery ul li { display: inline; }
#gallery ul img {
    border: 5px solid #3e3e3e;
    border-width: 5px 5px 20px;
}
#gallery ul a:hover img {
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-width: 5px 5px 20px;
    color: #fff;
}
#gallery ul a:hover { color: #fff; }
</style>
```

> notice that "#gallery ul li { display: inline; }" is inline, just
>   change it to "list-item", and there you go vertical position.

Downloads for LightBox is right [here](http://leandrovieira.com/download/7/).

Comment: Pressed the wrong button post question instead of post answer. Can some tell me how to change from question to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#gallery ul li { display: list-item; }
```